# Automate Tokens base login in Playwright. Java

Tags: playwright-python, playwright-test, playwright-sharp, playwright-java, playwright-dotnet

Scenario : To login to the application, need to enter the username and token sent on register email id.

How can we automate above scenario in playwright using java language.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The token change for every login? Or it is always the same? If it is the same, why you just use it for your scenario? Register an user, get the token created for that user and fill the login form with username and token.

Comment: Hi Jaky, Thanks for your response. Token is getting change every time.

Comment: Hi all, could you please help on this? Do you guys faced this kind of scenario before?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate your email login and collect the token from your email, then use the token for your main login. I think this process will help you and I don't think there are any other processes to do this scenario. You can use a different page for email login and token collection in the same browser context or can you use an entirely different browser context. I must tell you this approach is not a good way. Hope this will help you.